# Swift dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Charts.framework/Charts

Tags: swift, charts

I've a IOS swift application which uses 2 externs packages, 1) SwiftKeychainWrapper and 2) Charts. Both these packages have been installed using 'pod' and my Podfile is as follows,

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'Charts'

  # Pods for MyApp

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
```

target 'MyAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

I'm using Xcode version 9.2

Directory structure looks like this,

```
MyApp
...
...
Pods
    Podfile
    Frameworks
        iOS
            Foundation.framework
     Pods
         Charts
             Core
             Support Files
         SwiftkeychainWrapper
    Products
    Target Support Files
```

Under MyApp settings, I see following two interesting tabs,

```
 - General
      Embedded Binaries
         —
      Linked Frameworks and Libraries
         Name
         Pods_MyApp.framework
```

Both SwiftKeychainWrapper and Charts is installed using 'pod install'.

I also added "Charts.framework" under Linked Frameworks and Libraries but I got above error. I tried adding 'Charts.framework" under 'Embeddd section' but still got same error.

If I follow current instructions from https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts which says following,

```
Drag the Charts.xcodeproj to your project
Go to your target's settings, hit the "+" under the "Embedded Binaries" section, and select the Charts.framework
@import Charts
```

Which says to add this under 'Embedded binaries'. If I do that then the build fails for 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'.

BTW, this error happens when I tried to run it on my physical iphone6 device. It works ok on simulator. I really don't know how to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This turn out to be due to 'certificate issue'. After re-creating a new development cert on apple.com, this issue for resolved by itself.
One suggestion is, if you do see similar issue, just delete your certificates from the keychain access and recreate a new one. Do a clean build and run.

Answer (score 0):

Check Chart Framework add in General-> Embedded Binaries + --> ChartFramework.

if added change Embed column with 'Embed & sign'

and run.

It's work for me.